# Return value from function in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I want to get the last Saturday from today + 21 days.

In order to achieve this, I have written this script shown below. But the problem is that I can't get success to return the value from the result.

I want to create this function in SQL Server and will get this value in a stored procedure where I want.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME 
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME 
DECLARE @NumOfDays INT
DECLARE @resultDate smalldatetime

SET @StartDate = GETDATE()
SET @EndDate = GETDATE()+21
SET @NumOfDays = DATEDIFF(DD,@StartDate , @EndDate) + 1 ;

WITH Tens AS
(
    SELECT 1 N UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 1 
),
HUNDREDS AS
(
    SELECT T1.N FROM TENS T1 CROSS JOIN TENS T2
),
THOUSANDS AS
(
    SELECT T1.N FROM HUNDREDS T1 CROSS JOIN HUNDREDS T2
),
Numbers AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN FROM THOUSANDS
)
SELECT TOP 1  
    DATEADD(DD, (RN - 1), @StartDate) SaturdayDates
FROM 
    Numbers
WHERE 
    RN <= @NumOfDays 
    AND DATENAME (WEEKDAY, (DATEADD(DD, (RN - 1), @StartDate))) = 'Saturday' 
ORDER BY 
    SaturdayDates DESC
```

Can you please guide me to achieve my goal? Thanks

Comment: You didn't post any function, you posted a SELECT query that doesn't even return the single date you mentioned in the question

Comment: You want table-valued or scalar-valued function?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i want to create this script as a function that will return the value

Comment: @gofr1 table-value

Comment: What is the question then? The link to the `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax? Or are you asking why the query returns more than the single value you mention in the text? You can find the syntax by googling `T-SQL CREATE FUNCTION`, it's the first result

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my query will return only one value. Only i want to convert this script to function that will return the value as example i call SELECT dbo.fn_Get_NextSaturdayDay()

Comment: Did you try something ? Did you check the syntax of `CREATE FUNCTION`? You should probably clean up the statements too - is the value of `@NumOfDays` going to change?  Won't it always be the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just rewrite it like this **table-valued function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_NextSaturdayDay()
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    -- Add the SELECT statement with parameter references here
    WITH Tens AS
    (
        SELECT 1 N UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
    ),
    HUNDREDS AS
    (
        SELECT T1.N FROM TENS T1 CROSS JOIN TENS T2
    ),
    THOUSANDS AS
    (
        SELECT T1.N FROM HUNDREDS T1 CROSS JOIN HUNDREDS T2
    ),
    Numbers AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN FROM THOUSANDS
    )
    SELECT  TOP 1 DATEADD( DD,(RN - 1) , GETDATE() )  as SaturdayDates 
    FROM 
      Numbers
    WHERE 
      RN <= (DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE() , DATEADD(day,21,GETDATE()) ) + 1) AND DATENAME ( WEEKDAY, (DATEADD( DD,(RN - 1) , GETDATE() )) ) = 'Saturday' 

      ORDER BY SaturdayDates  DESC
)
GO
```

Than do:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Get_NextSaturdayDay()
```

Output:

```
SaturdayDates
2016-10-15 11:02:33.570
```

If you need **scalar-valued function**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Get_NextSaturdayDay ()
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @datetime datetime

    ;WITH Tens AS
    (
        SELECT 1 N UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
        SELECT 1 
    ),
    HUNDREDS AS
    (
        SELECT T1.N FROM TENS T1 CROSS JOIN TENS T2
    ),
    THOUSANDS AS
    (
        SELECT T1.N FROM HUNDREDS T1 CROSS JOIN HUNDREDS T2
    ),
    Numbers AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RN FROM THOUSANDS
    )
    SELECT  TOP 1 @datetime = DATEADD( DD,(RN - 1) , GETDATE() )
    FROM 
      Numbers
    WHERE 
      RN <= (DATEDIFF(DD,GETDATE() , DATEADD(day,21,GETDATE()) ) + 1) AND DATENAME ( WEEKDAY, (DATEADD( DD,(RN - 1) , GETDATE() )) ) = 'Saturday' 

      ORDER BY DATEADD( DD,(RN - 1) , GETDATE() ) DESC
        -- Return the result of the function
        RETURN @datetime

END
GO
```

Then run:

```
SELECT  dbo.Get_NextSaturdayDay()
```

Output:

```
2016-10-15 11:02:33.570
```

Comment: My pleasure! :)