# Use the same select in postgres several times

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-function

I have several updates, deletes and inserts in one transaction.
Want to make postgres function.
In all queries I have the same big part of conditions like:

```
WHERE smth IN (SELECT ... IN (SELECT ... ) AND ... NOT IN (SELECT ...) ...)
```

In fundamental of DRY, I don't want to copy-paste the same block of SQL query to each query. What the best way to separate this big SELECT to use it as varible or something likely in my function?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html

Comment: i found duplicate problem and solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786353/return-value-from-function-in-sql-server

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger query. These statements, which are often referred to as Common Table Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables that **exist just for one query**. Each auxiliary statement in a WITH clause can be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE; and the WITH clause itself is attached to a primary statement that can also be a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE.

**I can't use with in several queries.**

Comment: Your question does not indicate in any way that the query needs to be re-usable across different statements. You can create a view or a function if you need that